# gpg: skipped "12345689": Unusable secret key / how to use signing subkey for gpg?

Tags: git, gnupg, digital-signature, gpg-agent

As you see, I have a key with id 12345689, and I'm trying to sign with it in git

```
gpg -k
/home/lz/.gnupg/pubring.kbx
---------------------------
pub   rsa4096 2020-03-02 [C]
      12345689
uid           [ unknown] Person Person <me@person.com>
sub   rsa4096 2020-03-02 [S] [expires: 2024-03-01]
sub   rsa4096 2020-03-02 [E] [expires: 2024-03-01]
sub   rsa4096 2020-03-02 [A] [expires: 2024-03-01]
```

But git considers this key ID unusable:

```
gpg2 --status-fd=2 -bsau 12345689 1
[GNUPG:] KEY_CONSIDERED 12345689 1
gpg: skipped "12345689": Unusable secret key
[GNUPG:] INV_SGNR 9 12345689
[GNUPG:] FAILURE sign 54
gpg: signing failed: Unusable secret key
```

as I researched, it's because it contains `[C]` which is not for signing. I think I should use the subkey with `[S]` but how do I use it? I don't know how to get its ID. `gpg -k` does not show their IDs

Comment: When you specify a masterkey (or userid) gpg automatically uses the appropriate subkey. Your problem is not usage, it is accessing the _secret_ key. Try `gpg -K` with uppercase K (equivalent to `--list-secret-keys` instead of `--list-keys`) and also check you don't have pinentry set to something that doesn't work. Although you don't need the subkey id, you can see it (though not fingerprint) with `--keyid-format=long` or `--keyid-format=short`.

Comment: @dave_thompson_085 how should I access the subkey then? It's on a yubikey. I can login to SSH using this yubikey without any problems, but I can't use it for signing as you see

Comment: Okay, being on yubikey makes a big difference. Does `gpg -K` show `>` or `#` after `ssb` for the [S] key (and for [A] which is used for ssh, if you set ssh to go through gpg-agent and scdaemon)?

Comment: it shows `ssb#  rsa4096 2020-03-02 [S] [expires: 2024-03-01]
ssb#  rsa4096 2020-03-02 [E] [expires: 2024-03-01]
ssb>  rsa4096 2020-03-02 [A] [expires: 2024-03-01]
`

Comment: Please put that in the Q where it can be formatted correctly _and_ seen by others, since I know little about yubikey and can't help much more. [this](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/162336/where-can-i-find-the-detailed-manual-page-for-gpg-list-secret-keys-output) and [this](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/109638/gnupg-yubikey-4-how-to-manually-check-that-all-keys-are-where-they-belong-on) do confirm `ssb>` means it is on the card (and usable) while `ssb#` means it is unusable or missing. But you'll need someone else for _why_ it is unusable. Good luck.

Comment: Have you seen [Using Your YubiKey with OpenPGP](https://support.yubico.com/hc/en-us/articles/360013790259-Using-Your-YubiKey-with-OpenPGP)?

Comment: @harrymc yes and I used the last link to setup my yubikey. It works for SSH but not foe PGP